# How to serialize a class in MFC for win7?

Tags: serialization, windows-7, mfc

How to serialize a class in MFC for win7 ? 
My computer is win7 operation system, and install vs2008. if the code, which include serialize a class and  create a backup file, program the code as a execution File and run it in my computer is OK, it can open the serialized file and load data. but if the other win7 computer which not install vs2008, the execution File can not open the serialized file and load data is not success, but run in xp system is success.

I want to make my program can run win7 and xp,how to do it? thanks very much for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing your file in "non-appdata" folder, perhaps you are having problems with UAC. You can check for a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250810/how-to-make-your-mfc-application-bypass-uac-in-windows7-and-vista)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the DEBUG version of your program?

When you create a MFC program under Visual Studio, it creates a project that is 32-bit and uses the DEBUG version of MFC and the Runtime library.  When you get ready to distribute your program, make sure you build the RELEASE version which uses the non-DEBUG versions of MFC and the runtime library.  In all likelihood, the VS2008 runtime libraries will already be on your target Windows 7 computer.  If not, the user will have to download and install the Visual C++ 2008 runtime files from Microsoft.